# Hiding and showing left/right side files in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

But I always need to split window into 2.
1 is for test.js files and the other is for code file.
But sometimes I need to use full monitor for active editor.
To do this I want to hide left or right side for a moment.
Is there any shortcut, plugin, extension which can hide and show splitted editors?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maximize current group and after make it even again:

`"command": "workbench.action.maximizeEditor"`

`"command": "workbench.action.evenEditorWidths"`

Comment: What is the opposite of maximizeEditor? I want to restore back to normal view.

Comment: There might be some shortcut to seperate equal the two sides :)